# re-open jQuery UI Dialog and send data several times

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a simple **button** with id="new_customer". When clicked, a **jQuery UI dialog** opens with dynamic data in it.
When clicking the **custom button "save"** of the dialog, the content is sent to a php handler (stores the stuff into the database). So this works fine. 
BUT when I do this the second time, the content is sent to the handler and it's stored into database, but the dialog does not close. When I click the save button of the not closed dialog, I get the error message "*Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'*" in console.

```
$( "#new_customer" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault(event);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "libraries/factory/ajax/customers_handler.php",
        data: "customer_action=new_customer", 
        success: function( data ) {
                // write data into dialog div
                $( "#customer-dialog" ).html( data );
                // create the dialog
                $( "#customer-dialog" ).dialog({    
                    title: "New Customer",
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: [{
                            text:   "save",
                            click:  function() {
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "libraries/factory/ajax/customers_handler.php",
                                    data: $( "#customer_data_form" ).serialize() + "&customer_action=save_customer", 
                                    success: function( data ) {
                                        $( "#customer-dialog" ).dialog( "close" );
                                        $.ajax({
                                            type: "POST",
                                            url: "libraries/factory/ajax/customers_handler.php",
                                            data: "customer_action=load_customers_list", 
                                            success: function( data ) {
                                                $( "#customers_list_wrapper" ).html( data );
                                                createDataTable( "#customers_list" );
                                            }
                                        });

                                    },
                                    error: function( data ) {
                                        alert( data );
                                    },
                                    complete: function() {
                                        $( "#customer-dialog" ).dialog( "close" );
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                    }]
                });


        },
        error: function( data ) {
            alert( data );
        },
        complete: function() {

        }
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly, I found a solution.

I removed the success stuff from the save button function. Then I added $( this ).dialog( "close" ); and $( this ).remove(); after the ajax request.

```
$( "#customer-dialog" ).dialog({    
    title: "New Customer",
    modal: true,
    width: 600,
    height: 600,
    buttons: [{
        text:   "save",
        click:  function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "libraries/factory/ajax/customers_handler.php",
                data: $( "#customer_data_form" ).serialize() + "&customer_action=save_customer", 
                success: function( data ) {
                    console.log( data );
                    $( "#customer-dialog" ).html( "" );
                    $( "#customer-dialog" ).dialog( "close" );
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "libraries/factory/ajax/customers_handler.php",
                        data: "customer_action=load_customers_list", 
                        success: function( data ) {
                            $( "#customers_list_wrapper" ).html( data );
                            createDataTable( "#customers_list" );
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function( data ) {
                    alert( data );
                }
            });
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            $( this ).remove();
        }
    }]
});
```